# How to delete Search History in Outlook 2016

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

How can I delete the search history in Outlook 2016 on Windows 10?

I followed the steps in this artice, but it doesn't work. The search entries are still there.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/outlook-2016-deleteing-searched-items/e00202c9-99c7-460d-ab56-dbf30e832c06

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can delete the search history in the "Recent Searches" area, via the steps in the link you mentioned:

> [image: area]

However, you can not delete the search history in this area:

> [image: can't delete here]

Comment: That's correct, but I want to delete the entries in the 2nd area you wrote.